# how make scrollable all mobile page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Do you know how make scrollable all mobile page in flutter ? Because if we display some widgets it générâtes an error if it is more of the height of the mobile screen

Comment: You can wrap your widget with  ListView or SingleChildScrollView. [Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158031/how-to-make-a-screen-scrollable-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

This would work perfectly. Check it out.

```
ListView(
     children: <Widget>[
        // first widget here
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        // third widget here
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        // second widget here
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListView`

```
Widget view(){
    return ListView(
        children: <Widget[
             Text("your widgets here"), 
             SizedBox(height: 20), // you can use these for spacing
        ]
    )
}
```

Or a `SingleChildScrollView`

```
Widget view(){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        children: <Widget[
             Text("your widgets here"), 
             SizedBox(height: 20), // you can use these for spacing
        ]
    )
}
```